# Bpel Deployment Failed with Oracle db wso2 BPS 3.5.0

Tags: wso2, datasource, bpel, wso2-business-process

I have changed H2 the WSO2_CARBON_DB and BPSDB and activity DB with ORACLE.
The version of BPS is 3.5.0

I have found this issue https://wso2.org/jira/browse/BPS-185 but is fixed on this release.

Now when I do a deploy there is this error :

[2015-11-05 14:35:11,692]  WARN {Transaction} -  Unexpected exception from beforeCompletion; transaction will roll back
 org.apache.openjpa.persistence.InvalidStateException: Attempt to commit a null javax.transaction.Transaction.  Some application servers set the transaction to null if a rollback occurs.
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.setRollbackOnlyInternal(BrokerImpl.java:1654)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.setRollbackOnly(BrokerImpl.java:1640)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.setRollbackOnly(DelegatingBroker.java:981)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.setRollbackOnly(EntityManagerImpl.java:631)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceExceptions$2.translate(PersistenceExceptions.java:77)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.translateManagedCompletionException(BrokerImpl.java:2060)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.beforeCompletion(BrokerImpl.java:1994)
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.beforeCompletion(TransactionImpl.java:514)
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.beforeCompletion(TransactionImpl.java:498)
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.beforePrepare(TransactionImpl.java:400)
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:257)
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:238)
    at org.apache.ode.store.jpa.DbConfStoreConnectionFactory.commitTransaction(DbConfStoreConnectionFactory.java:86)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.store.ProcessStoreImpl$Callable.call(ProcessStoreImpl.java:739)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-11-05 14:35:11,696] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.store.ProcessStoreImpl} -  DbError
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transaction associated with current thread
    at org.apache.ode.store.jpa.DbConfStoreConnectionFactory.rollbackTransaction(DbConfStoreConnectionFactory.java:97)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.store.ProcessStoreImpl$Callable.call(ProcessStoreImpl.java:745)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transaction associated with current thread
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerImpl.rollback(TransactionManagerImpl.java:247)
    at org.apache.ode.store.jpa.DbConfStoreConnectionFactory.rollbackTransaction(DbConfStoreConnectionFactory.java:95)
    ... 5 more
[2015-11-05 14:35:11,697] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.store.TenantProcessStoreImpl} -  BPEL Package deployment failed at ODE layer. Possible cause: DbError
org.apache.ode.bpel.iapi.ContextException: DbError
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.store.ProcessStoreImpl.exec(ProcessStoreImpl.java:775)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.store.ProcessStoreImpl.onBPELPackageDeployment(ProcessStoreImpl.java:332)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.store.TenantProcessStoreImpl.deployBPELPackageInODE(TenantProcessStoreImpl.java:703)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.store.TenantProcessStoreImpl.deploy(TenantProcessStoreImpl.java:243)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.deployer.BPELDeployer.deploy(BPELDeployer.java:107)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadServices(DeploymentEngine.java:135)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.deployServices(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:567)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.DeploymentServerStartupObserver.completingServerStartup(DeploymentServerStartupObserver.java:51)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.notifyBefore(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:235)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.completeInitialization(StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.java:185)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.serviceChanged(StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
    at org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.internal.ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.registerThrottlingAgent(ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.java:123)
    at org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.internal.ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.activate(ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:517)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:219)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5550)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Unable to commit: transaction marked for rollback
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.store.ProcessStoreImpl.exec(ProcessStoreImpl.java:773)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Unable to commit: transaction marked for rollback
    at org.apache.ode.store.jpa.DbConfStoreConnectionFactory.commitTransaction(DbConfStoreConnectionFactory.java:88)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.store.ProcessStoreImpl$Callable.call(ProcessStoreImpl.java:739)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Unable to commit: transaction marked for rollback
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:271)
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:238)
    at org.apache.ode.store.jpa.DbConfStoreConnectionFactory.commitTransaction(DbConfStoreConnectionFactory.java:86)
    ... 5 more
[2015-11-05 14:35:11,703] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.deployer.BPELDeployer} -  Error deploying BPEL package: SBIC_1.0.0.zip
org.apache.ode.bpel.iapi.ContextException: DbError
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.store.ProcessStoreImpl.exec(ProcessStoreImpl.java:775)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.store.ProcessStoreImpl.onBPELPackageDeployment(ProcessStoreImpl.java:332)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.store.TenantProcessStoreImpl.deployBPELPackageInODE(TenantProcessStoreImpl.java:703)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.store.TenantProcessStoreImpl.deploy(TenantProcessStoreImpl.java:243)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.deployer.BPELDeployer.deploy(BPELDeployer.java:107)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadServices(DeploymentEngine.java:135)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.deployServices(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:567)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.DeploymentServerStartupObserver.completingServerStartup(DeploymentServerStartupObserver.java:51)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.notifyBefore(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:235)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.completeInitialization(StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.java:185)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.serviceChanged(StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
    at org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.internal.ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.registerThrottlingAgent(ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.java:123)
    at org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.internal.ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.activate(ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:517)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:219)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5550)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Unable to commit: transaction marked for rollback
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.store.ProcessStoreImpl.exec(ProcessStoreImpl.java:773)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Unable to commit: transaction marked for rollback
    at org.apache.ode.store.jpa.DbConfStoreConnectionFactory.commitTransaction(DbConfStoreConnectionFactory.java:88)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.store.ProcessStoreImpl$Callable.call(ProcessStoreImpl.java:739)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Unable to commit: transaction marked for rollback
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:271)
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:238)
    at org.apache.ode.store.jpa.DbConfStoreConnectionFactory.commitTransaction(DbConfStoreConnectionFactory.java:86)
    ... 5 more

Comment: make sure that <defaultAutoCommit>true</defaultAutoCommit> entry is added in the bps-datasource.xml config.

Comment: Thank now work well, please add the answer to this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure that `<defaultAutoCommit>true</defaultAutoCommit>` entry is added in the bps-datasource.xml config.